# Froala Editor / Drag and Drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, froala

I am trying to achieve some custom drop event functionality with the Froala Editor. They have a very basic example on codepen here: [Drag Drop Example](http://codepen.io/Froala/pen/PpgdRb)

The trouble is that this doesnt work -  I can't get the custom 'froalaEditor.drop' function to fire, I am sure I need to add some sort of 'prevent default' somewhere for the HTML5 drop events but everything I have tried either kills all drop functionality or does nothing. The custom function looks like this:

```
$('div#froala-editor').froalaEditor({
  toolbarButtons: ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'insertImage', 'insertLink', 'emoticons', 'undo', 'redo'],
  pluginsEnabled: ['image', 'link', 'draggable', 'emoticons']
})
.on ('froalaEditor.drop', function (e, editor, dropEvent) {
//// do stuff - nothing is firing
```

I am making this draggable via the standard:

```
draggable="true"
```

Any help or pointers with this would be much appreciated!

Thanks,

Mark

UPDATE:::

Here is my JS:

```
$(function() {
// For Firefox to work.
$("#drag-smile, #drag-text").on("dragstart", function(e) {
    e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData("Text", this.id);
});

$("div#froala-editor")
    .froalaEditor({
        toolbarButtons: [
            "bold",
            "italic",
            "underline",
            "insertImage",
            "insertLink",
            "emoticons",
            "undo",
            "redo"
        ],
        pluginsEnabled: ["image", "link", "draggable", "emoticons"]
    })
    .on("froalaEditor.drop", function(e, editor, dropEvent) {
        // Focus at the current posisiton.
        editor.markers.insertAtPoint(dropEvent.originalEvent);
        var $marker = editor.$el.find(".fr-marker");
        $marker.replaceWith($.FroalaEditor.MARKERS);
        editor.selection.restore();

        // Save into undo stack the current position.
        if (!editor.undo.canDo()) editor.undo.saveStep();

        // Insert HTML.
        if (dropEvent.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData("Text") == "drag-smile") {
            editor.html.insert(
                '<span class="fr-emoticon fr-emoticon-img" style="background: url(https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/emojione/2.0.1/assets/svg/1f600.svg)">&nbsp;</span>'
            );
        } else {
            editor.html.insert("Hello!");
        }

        // Save into undo stack the changes.
        editor.undo.saveStep();

        // Stop event propagation.
        dropEvent.preventDefault();
        dropEvent.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    });
   });
```

And my HTML:

```
   <div id="drag-smile" style="border: solid 1px #CCC; padding: 5px; width: 300px;" draggable="true"><img src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/emojione/2.0.1/assets/svg/1f600.svg" width="32" /> Drag Me to insert a smile.</div><br/>
<div id="drag-text" style="border: solid 1px #CCC; padding: 5px; width: 300px;" draggable="true">Drag Me to insert some text.</div><br/>
<div id="froala-editor">
<h3>Click here to edit the content</h3>
<p>The image can be dragged only between blocks and not inside them.
</p>
</div>
```

Essentially when you drag one of the draggable divs into the editor, custom html should be injected to the editor but instead it just adds the divs id as text.

Comment: are you having a `<div id="froala-editor">` tag in your html structure?

Comment: Hi, yes the editor initialises correctly on the div with that ID, its just the drop event doesn't seem to connect properly.

Comment: if you don't mind sharing your whole html and js code it would help a lot in finding the issue, because i don't think the problem is in the currently shared snippet

Comment: what browser are you using? i've noticed the example from codepen works well in firefox and has some issues in chrome

Comment: Your right, I just tested in firefox and it works as expected, I had only tested in chrome and safari... any ideas as to why that might be happening?

Comment: After further inspection it would appear chrome is throwing an error "Discontiguous selection is not supported." After a bit of googling I tried adding `window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();` but it hasn't fixed the error.

Answer (score 2):

That's because the drop event is being stopped before it gets to your callback. Change it like this to make sure your event is always being called first:

```js
$("div#froala-editor")
.on("froalaEditor.initialized", function(e, editor, dropEvent) {

    editor.events.on('drop', function (dropEvent) {
        // Focus at the current posisiton.
        editor.markers.insertAtPoint(dropEvent.originalEvent);
        var $marker = editor.$el.find(".fr-marker");
        $marker.replaceWith($.FroalaEditor.MARKERS);
        editor.selection.restore();

        // Save into undo stack the current position.
        if (!editor.undo.canDo()) editor.undo.saveStep();

        // Insert HTML.
        if (dropEvent.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData("Text") == "drag-smile") {
            editor.html.insert(
                '<span class="fr-emoticon fr-emoticon-img" style="background: url(https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/emojione/2.0.1/assets/svg/1f600.svg)">&nbsp;</span>'
            );
        } else {
            editor.html.insert("Hello!");
        }

        // Save into undo stack the changes.
        editor.undo.saveStep();

        // Stop event propagation.
        dropEvent.preventDefault();
        dropEvent.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    }, true);
});
.froalaEditor({
    toolbarButtons: [
        "bold",
        "italic",
        "underline",
        "insertImage",
        "insertLink",
        "emoticons",
        "undo",
        "redo"
    ],
    pluginsEnabled: ["image", "link", "draggable", "emoticons"]
})
```

});